# How can I get to Nanaimo from Vancouver airport?

Tags: canada, transportation, vancouver-island

How can I get to Nanaimo from Vancouver airport?

By ferry? airplane?

Where can I reserve the ticket to Nanaimo?
Plus, I don't have vehicle.

Comment: It's expected that you do some research of your own before posting a question here.  Searching Google for "vancouver to nanaimo" turns up lots of information on ferries.

Answer (score 4):

You can fly in 20 minutes, tickets from $75, or take a ferry in two hours for $11-13.  Bus #5 goes to the ferry terminal at Horseshoe Bay.

For this and any other "A to B" question: http://www.rome2rio.com/s/Vancouver/Nanaimo

Answer (score 3):

The easiest cheap way is BC Ferries, from Tsawwassen or Horseshoe Bay.

Steps:

([Tsawwassen ferry](http://www.bcferries.com/schedules/mainland/tsdp-current.php))

- Skytrain to Bridgeport station, bus to Tsawwassen ferry.
- Take ferry to Duke Point, Nanaimo.

([Horseshoe Bay ferry](http://www.bcferries.com/schedules/mainland/hbna-current.php))

- Skytrain (2 zone ticket) from Vancouver airport to Vancouver Central City station.
- Bus to Horseshoe Bay
- Ferry to Departure Bay, Nanaimo

(source: I've been to both Vancouver terminals, and taken the ferry to Nanaimo and back twice, both times from Horseshoe Bay).

There are flights (check [kayak.com](http://kayak.com/)) but the ferry will be considerably cheaper.